# ggplot2 labeling scatter points in R

Tags: r, text, ggplot2

Trying to Label my scatter points in R. This is my first plot, very straight forward but can't seem to figure out adding text. I've looked at some of the other posts in here and they partially make sense but i just don't understand the lingo yet.

```
stats <- read.csv(file.choose())
qplot(data=stats, x=Avg.of.FD.Points, y=Avg.FD.Dev)
text(x, y, label=Home.Skater)

Home.Skater   Avg.of.FD.Points  Avg.FD.Dev
A.J. Greer    |   4.27        | 2.84
Aaron Ekblad  |   12.40       | 6.22
Aaron Ness    |   5.60        | 4.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple scatterplot example with `geom_text` based on your sample data.

```
df <- read.table(text = 
    "Home.Skater      Avg.FD.PTS   Avg.FD.Dev
    A.J._Greer       4.27       2.84
    Aaron_Ekblad     12.40      6.22
    Aaron_Ness       5.60       4.00", header = T);

require(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = Avg.FD.PTS, y = Avg.FD.Dev, label = Home.Skater)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text(hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.05) + 
    xlim(0, 15);
```

[image]

To avoid cluttering of (many) labels, you may want to consider the R library [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).

Comment: Say you didn't convert that to a df, what would it be with just data=stats? Tried running what you had but changed df to data and that didn't work. i  install.packages ggrepel. How do i add the ggrepel to it?

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson In my example, the output of `read.table` is already a `dataframe`. `ggplot` takes a `dataframe` as `data` input argument; so I'm not sure what you mean? I assume `stats` is already a `dataframe`? In that case it should be `ggplot(data = stats, aes(...)) + ...`.

Comment: yes it is. If i  run `require(ggplot2);
ggplot(data, aes(x = Avg.FD.PTS, y = Avg.FD.Dev, label = Home.Skater)) + 
+   geom_point() + 
+   geom_text(hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.05) + 
+   xlim(0, 15);`     I get Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Ah, now I understand. It should be `ggplot(data = stats, aes(x = Avg.FD.PTS, y = Avg.FD.Dev, label = Home.Skater)) + ...`. `data` is the name of the `ggplot` function argument.

Comment: Awesome, that's it! Thanks for dumbing it down. With 734 rows I really need to figure out the ggrepel library!

Comment: Great, glad to help @MichaelTJohnson . Good luck with `ggrepel`. If you understand the vanilla `ggplot2` syntax, `ggrepel` will be straightforward. For example, to start, all you'd need to do is replace `geom_text(...)` with `geom_text_repel(...)`. The `ggrepel` link in my answer has some nice examples.